# MooTools: Get child nodes

Tags: css-selectors, mootools

I have the ID of an element. I want to retrieve all child *elements* and all text *nodes*. Is there a way to do this in MooTools?

For example, say I have this markup:

```
<div id="foobar">
    test <img />
</div>
```

How can I use $('foobar') to select both text node "test" and element "img", like they're siblings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[get()](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:get)** function to get specific properties of an element that have been set in the [Element.properties](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element-Properties) hash ('html','text' or 'tag' are set by default):

```
alert($('foobar').get('text'));  //alerts 'test'
```

And you can use the **[getChildren()](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:getChildren)** function to get the set of child elements.  `getChildren()` function can take a match, so you could use `$('foobar').getChildren('img')` to return just the `img` element, or simply `$('foobar').getChildren()` to return all elements.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you have given, you can't get "test" as a text node because it's a property of the "foobar" div.
If you want to get both nodes you can get the child nodes and the div itself: http://mootools.net/shell/NG3Yn/

However, like @zombat has pointed out, you will have to use get and set('text') in order to manipulate the text.